# VS.NET = my app needs to run in compatibility mode

Tags: windows, visual-studio, forms, compatibility

I am developing an application that uses a library to control an OLYMPUS camera - the library is from OLYMPUS.

I am running vs.net 2012 in Windows 8.

This app use to work in vs.net under windows 7. In windows 8 the camera is not seen and the app does not work. So I built my app and set on the .exe run in XP Compatibility mode and the app works and the camera is seen.

However I cannot develop my application like this - is there a way to set the application to run in compatibility mode while debugging in vs.net?

Comment: I have found that instead of using "Start Project" and using "Start Executable" and specifying my .EXE file in the application properties / Debug options it allows me to work with the application and it works with the camera. So all good I think.

Comment: If what you commented on fixed your problem you should add it as an answer to your question. Then if anything better doesn't come along you can accept it.